# Java Google Plus Access via oAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I tried many different things to access a google Account in order to read out profile-data, but it failed every time.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

I tried to access via following code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static GoogleAccessProtectedResource connect(String CLIENT_ID,String CLIENT_SECRET,String SCOPE,String CALLBACK_URL,HttpTransport TRANSPORT,JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY) throws IOException{
    // Generate the URL to which we will direct users
        String authorizeUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID,
            CALLBACK_URL, SCOPE).build();
        System.out.println("Paste this url in your browser: " + authorizeUrl);

        // Wait for the authorization code
        System.out.println("Type the code you received here: ");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String authorizationCode = in.readLine();

        // Exchange for an access and refresh token
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant authRequest = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(TRANSPORT,
            JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, CALLBACK_URL);
        authRequest.useBasicAuthorization = false;
        AccessTokenResponse authResponse = authRequest.execute();
        String accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;
        GoogleAccessProtectedResource access = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken,
            TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authResponse.refreshToken);
        HttpRequestFactory rf = TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(access);
        System.out.println("Access token: " + authResponse.accessToken);

        // Make an authenticated request
        GenericUrl shortenEndpoint = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");
        String requestBody =
            "{\"longUrl\":\"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5281/5686001474_e06f1587ff_o.jpg\"}";
        HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(shortenEndpoint,
            ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", requestBody));
        HttpResponse shortUrl = request.execute();
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shortUrl.getContent()));
        System.out.println("Shorten Response: ");
        for (String line = output.readLine(); line != null; line = output.readLine()) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }

        // Refresh a token (SHOULD ONLY BE DONE WHEN ACCESS TOKEN EXPIRES)
        //access.refreshToken();
        //System.out.println("Original Token: " + accessToken + " New Token: " + access.getAccessToken());

        return access;


  }
```

Then i want to access my account

```
public static void getData1(String accessToken, String clientId, String clientSecret, String refreshToken) throws IOException{
    // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

      // Set up OAuth 2.0 access of protected resources
      // using the refresh and access tokens, automatically
      // refreshing the access token when it expires
      GoogleAccessProtectedResource requestInitializer =
          new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken, httpTransport,
          jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken);

      // Set up the main Google+ class
      Plus plus = Plus.builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
          .setHttpRequestInitializer(requestInitializer)
          .build();

      // Make a request to access your profile and display it to console
      Person profile = plus.people().get("[myID]").execute();
      System.out.println("ID: " + profile.getId());
      System.out.println("Name: " + profile.getDisplayName());
      System.out.println("Image URL: " + profile.getImage().getUrl());
      System.out.println("Profile URL: " + profile.getUrl());
  }
```

Following main method should work afterwards: `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` are created

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  GoogleAccessProtectedResource access1=Connection.connect(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE, CALLBACK_URL, TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);

  //refresh
  String token= access1.getAccessToken();
  access1.refreshToken();
  String refreshed=access1.getAccessToken(); 
//get data
    Connection.getData1(token, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, refreshed); 
}
```

This is my Data...

```
private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener";
private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

// FILL THESE IN WITH YOUR VALUES FROM THE API CONSOLE
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "[myID].apps.googleusercontent.com";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "[myID]";
```

---

Now there is a bad Request Exception thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad  Request
{
 "error" : "invalid_client"
}
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:900)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.executeUnparsed(AccessTokenRequest.java:472)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.execute(AccessTokenRequest.java:486)
at Connection.connect(Connection.java:78)
at Connection.main(Connection.java:50)
```

Comment: its working now!
i cannot explain what went wrong, i copy pasted the clientid and secret again and it worked.
But its much better and easier if you use the google plus java starter project: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hopefully pretty easy to fix.

You're using a SCOPE string of:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener`

This is the scope for the URL Shortener (goo.gl) API, not the Google+ APIs.  Instead you should probably try using the profile scope for Google+

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`

Documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Above, it looks like you're using [myID] to reference two different types of ID:

In the below statement, the myID should be your Google+ profile ID (copied/pasted from the URL for your Google+ profile or instead use the string 'me' to represent the currently authorized user):

`Person profile = plus.people().get("[myID]").execute();`

However, for the CLIENT_ID, you should be using the values from your project in code.google.com/apis/console.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, i tried to fix it with your suggestions, but it does not work...
I changed teh SCOPE as you mentioned.
For the [myID] i used the two different types of IDs. I only want to hide them ;)

Comment: What exception are you seeing now that you're using the correct scope?

Comment: I added a new Answer to this topic below, because it was not able to post code into the Comment!
HttpResponseException was was thrown.
By the way. I am working on my Bachelor Thesis and i need to get and export Profile Data of my Profile on Google+.
Is this the right way?

Comment: the best you can do is using the google plus java starter project:
see here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/